# Isomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to itself

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Let $\phi$ be an isomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x,y]$.
Two possible choices for $\phi$ are easy to see, namely the identity map and the map
that switches $x$ and $y$. I was wondering, are there any other isomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x,y]$ out there? Thanks!

Comment: I think it will work $(a_1,a_2,....a_k) \to (a_k,a_{k-1},....a_1)$. Reverse the coefficients.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example of what you mean? I don't quite get what you mean here. Thanks!

Comment: Reversing coefficients is far from being well-defined or even an algebra homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $k$-linear isomorphisms $k^2 \to k^2$ besides the identity and the map that switches the two coordinates. They all give ring automorphisms of $k[x,y]$; for example the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ corresponds to the automorphism $x \mapsto x$, $y \mapsto x + y$.

This comes from the fact that $k[x,y]$ is the free commutative $k$-algebra on $k^2$ (where the first coordinate corresponds to $x$ and the second to $y$), thus an automorphism of the vector space $k^2$ induces an automorphism of $k[x,y]$.

Comment: This assumes you're talking about $k$-algebra isomorphisms, of course.

Comment: I was thinking of just ring homomorphisms. I wonder if the result still holds? Thanks!

Comment: Well a $k$-algebra homomorphism is in particular a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Right. I meant could there be a ring isomorphism (sending 1 to 1), but not $k$-algebra isomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to itself?

Comment: But there *are* $k$-algebra isomorphisms that are neither the identity nor the switch of $x$ and $y$. And in particular these are some of the ring isomorphisms $k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ you wanted.

Comment: Oops. I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example 
$$
x \mapsto  x+y,\ y \mapsto x-y
$$
or more generally 
$$
x \mapsto  x+f(y),\ y \mapsto y+g(x+f(y)), f,g - \text{one variable polynomials }
$$
is such an automorphism.